# VTK: What does setExtent, setOrigin, setSpacing means in a 3D image?

Tags: 3d, vtk

I understand that this can be a very basic VTK image processing question. After reading api documentation, I can't fully comprehend the idea.

My question: What does setExtent, setOrigin and setSpacing means in a 3D image using vtkImageData ?

Position_in_space_point = origin + spacing. Then why do we need to setExtent?

From  http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkImageData.html#a08f18365c7178f8f595b08403db27a55, it says that setExtent is defined by the first and last point on each axis. Am I missing something?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These settings specifies the dimension and position of your vtkImageData object.

SetExtent sets the dimensions in each axis.
e.g. a dataset of 50 images and width/height of 512/512

```
myVtkImageData->SetExtent(0,511,0,511,0,49);
```

SetSpacing sets the size of a voxel (size in each direction x,y,z) in your dataset.

(default)

```
myVtkImageData->SetSpacing(1,1,1);
```

SetOrigin sets the position in 3D space of point 0 0 0 (first pixel)

(default)

```
myVtkImageData->SetOrigin(0,0,0)
```

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning that the image's extent is not required to have point [0, 0, 0]. Thus specifying that point as the "first" pixel is usually true since most times that's how it used but not required to be that way.